# What are the sustainability impacts of requiring more and more years of education?

Tags: energy, economy, family

As time has gone on, education requirements to meaningfully have a career has increased incrementally over time.  This is true across virtually all fields.  This means that we start careers later, are more dependent on corporate jobs, and have to invest much more in our own children's education and development than generations in the past have done.  Is this a good or a bad thing in terms of sustainability?

My initial guesses are:

1. More time living alone means more energy consumption.
2. Fewer children may have both positive and negative effects.  For example, having fewer than two children makes it socially harder for people to expect to move in with their kids upon retirement.  On the other hand, people consume resources....
3. Less career time means less overall energy available for manual production.  The job functions necessarily become oversight functions, and the labor is automated via cheap energy sources like fossil fuels.  This leads to less flexibility regarding reducing energy usage.
4. Less time and flexibility to make informed choices regarding sustainability because of additional burdens like student loans requiring additional efforts to make ends meet.

My guess is that this should be a negative factor sustainability-wise.  Is this far wrong?

Comment: It's even more complicated. For example, more time on studies means better education and (at least in theory) more opportunities to learn sustainable ways of life. I would expect a book, not an ordinary answer to thogourhly map this problematics - and without considering tens or even hunderds of factors, you won't be able to tell whether pluses or minuses prevail. I would guess it's a mixed blessing which may lead both to better or worse sustainability depending on the way how the additional years of education are spend.

Comment: Hmmm and the plusses and minuses may be different in nature as much as different in quantity, meaning they may not win.....  That's a good point.  Any suggestions for narrowing this?

Comment: Being in education doesn't necessarily mean that you live unsustainably, although your focus on books may take away your focus on sustainable living and cause you to opt for more convenient, unsustainable options, because as of this moment they are more readily available. But then, this can be said not only about education, but about work in general. Surely a longer working day is less sustainable. As it stands, I don't think this is a very good question.

Comment: @user1205935 certainly we need people in education but I dont think that is what I am getting at.  The question is whether gradual increases in the amount of education required (which we know affect everything from birth rate to retirement options) are significant problems sustainability-wise.  This isn't about working in education so much as when to start one's economic and family life.

Comment: @user1205935 suggestions on clarifying/improving this would be welcome.

Comment: I just think that "gradual increases in the amount of education required" is part of a bigger picture, in which people work longer in more specialized areas (for which they need more education). Who grows their own herbs on their porch nowadays? I am thinking it would be less and less people, because they don't have time. You could also say that "More education means more people commuting to school, which means greater use of fossil fuels. Therefore education is unsustainable.", which is hardly the big picture. Unfortunately, these comments are not enough to discuss the issue at length.

Comment: @user1205935 it is a part of a bigger picture, as was the independent retirement question I posted earlier.  And like the independent retirement question it gets to the question of sustainable family structure.  If independent retirement is less sustainable than retiring with the kids generally...  Additionally it isn't a question about education per se, so much as it is a question about a trend of specialization.  Is there a real complexity cost that translates into a resources cost?  I am guessing that there is but it is hard to say.

Comment: I am going to suggest we close this as non-constructive (I would prefer not to delete it because I think Nate's answer is worth keeping).  I will however post a different view to my blog and post a link here.  Apologies since this seems to be less conducive to existing studies, facts, and figures than I had hoped!

Comment: @user1205935, I have voted to close as non-constructive.  Feel free to make that so if you'd like :-)

Answer (score 4):

Before responding to your questions in turn, I'd like to propose that I think this issue behaves somewhat like [the (justifiably) maligned Laffer curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laffer_curve).  In other words, I think it's clear that with **no** education, humans would still be stuck in primitive societies, which **were** sustainable, and involved small per capita resource usage.  As education increases, you do get an increase in resource consumption, with a standard-of-living increase.  However, I believe that in the future, we can achieve lower levels of resource consumption again, with further **increases** in education.

> More time living alone means more energy consumption.

Staying in school doesn't just mean *"living alone"*.  It probably also means living modestly, in a small apartment.  And it often does mean living with roommates.  The people at both the universities I went to (in the US) all lived with small energy and spatial footprints, relative to working adults in the surrounding society.  So, I'd say this issue favors staying in school, as more sustainable.

[A link on CO<sub>2</sub> footprint vs. age that reflects this issue](http://green.blogs.nytimes.com/2011/11/10/if-you-act-your-age-whats-your-carbon-footprint/), although school vs. work at the same age is not teased apart.

> Fewer children may have both positive and negative effects.

While, technically this is true (there are positive **and** negative effects), I strongly disagree with the implied equivalency.  Human beings consume lots of resources.  Lots.  In those countries where higher education is a realistic option (as posed in your question), humans consume even more resources.  More humans fundamentally means more resource consumption.  Not to mention the basic math that birth rates above the [replacement rate](http://www.wikigender.org/index.php/Replacement_rate) are *inherently* unsustainable, as long as we're bound to this one planet.

> Less career time means less overall energy available for manual production.

Exactly.  As I alluded to earlier, students do have lower environmental footprints than an average working adult.  The amount of work output by today's current population vastly exceeds that required to fulfill basic human needs (as evidenced by many of us working in jobs that are not fundamentally **necessary**).  We need people to be working at jobs **less** than they do now (in the developed world), and producing less.  I'm not advocating education simply on the grounds that it takes time away from production, but I do believe that's a beneficial side effect.

> and the labor is automated via cheap energy sources like fossil fuels. This leads to less flexibility regarding reducing energy usage.

Labor will be automated regardless, and less educated workers could actually provide more incentive to automate.  I've seen a number of your posts on the site that suggest to me that you think *automation* fundamentally increases energy usage.  While that could be its own separate discussion, I'll merely assert here that I find that to be false (and my apologies if that's not actually your belief).

> Less time and flexibility to make informed choices regarding sustainability because of additional burdens like student loans requiring additional efforts to make ends meet.

First of all, you **can't** make informed choices without education.  Education underlies all decision-making.  If there's any obstacle to sustainability today in the US (where I live), it's **ignorance** of the basic science that supports consensus thinking on climate change.  While there are educated skeptics who simply don't trust climate science, want more data, or believe the solution is elsewhere (not sustainability, but something like *geoengineering*), the majority here are skeptical because of a lack of basic understanding of the science.  I believe a subject like this, while possible to treat at the high school level, is probably better expanded on at universities.

Finally, at least in the US, it's not true that taking out student loans requires working more to make ends meet.  It's precisely the opposite.  [Higher levels of education reap higher lifetime earnings](http://www.census.gov/prod/2002pubs/p23-210.pdf) by an amount that easily pays for the cost of the extra education (plus interest).  Granted, that equation is going to be different in every country, as tuition rates vary, as do student loan interest rates.  But, based simply on the example of the world's largest developed economy, you do **not** wind up having to work more simply because you paid for more education.  You may *choose* to work more, because you have a more enjoyable career, or have suffered less *wear-and-tear* from a white collar career.  But, that's a separate point.

Comment: This is sort of what I am getting at with positive and negative impacts though, when you say, " In those countries where higher education is a realistic option (as posed in your question), humans consume even more resources."  That seems to suggest that increases in education *increase* resource consumption of kids making fewer kids a requirement.  Is that correct (that the issue is less "equivalency" but "interdependency")?

Comment: One other requests for clarification:  "First of all, you can't make informed choices without education..."  Would you say that we make better sustainability decisions than than the uneducated rice farmer in Kampuchea?  If we taught the rice farmer modern science, would this improve the sustainability of the farming practices?

Comment: @ChrisTravers, to your first comment.  This is one area where it's difficult to separate correlation from causation.  Is more education *causing* more resource consumption?  Or is more resource consumption fueling economic growth (unsustainably, of course), which allows us to be in a position to attain higher levels of education?  If you look at history, I believe the unsustainable resource consumption came first.  The industrial revolution ushered in massive burning of oil and coal, while the average worker was still quite poorly educated.  I believe fewer kids is a requirement either way ...

Comment: ... as the sustainable living habits of early humans simply do not scale to 7 billion people at all.  Certainly not politically, given that we've already tasted modern life.  I would agree that we **don't** make better sustainability decisions than the poor rice farmer.  This is the Laffer Curve analogy I was positing.  I think, relative to the rice farmer, initial increases in education lead to less sustainability.  I think (hope!) that there reaches a point, however, where **more** education starts heading in the direction of more sustainable living again.  I say this partially because I ...

Comment: ... think that we were actually pretty close to a tipping point.  In the US, for example, prior to the financial crisis, public consensus was building that climate change was real, and a problem.  Economic issues pushed public opinion in the direction of denialism, and as the US is the world's largest economy, that's had a big effect on stalling progress.  However, I don't think we're so far off that another 10 years couldn't reverse the trend.  Lots of climate disasters might do it, but I think a better understanding of science would help, too.  I simply see too much thinking here along ...

Comment: ... the lines of "CO2 is natural, so it must be ok", or "the earth has warmed before, so what's the problem", or "isn't the ice sheet growing around the south pole"?  All these objections are really easily dismissed with a basic understanding of science.  Anyway, *science* is only one part of education.  I certainly believe in the value of the other parts, too.  But, as it relates to sustainability, I think it's crucial.  Certainly, just my opinion, though.

Comment: I am noticing a couple things which make me think maybe this question should be closed as non-constructive.  The big thing is that it seems that any possible answer here is probably based on unprovable assumptions, hopes, and beliefs.  And one of the huge issues with "the earth has warmed before" (regarding, say, the medieval warming period) is that the climate data that is available is simply inadequate to say that it did (or not!).  It's not like we had global scientific satellites measuring the climate a thousand years ago.

Comment: @ChrisTravers, not true.  Satellite measurements are just *one* way to measure temperature.  That's what the field of *paleoclimatology* is all about: using things like ice cores (which contain ancient air samples), sea fossils and coral, or tree rings (living and fossilized) to deduce climate data.  Anyway, I agree that it's hard to discuss this particular question (education & sustainability) in typical Q+A style.  This requires some good social science research to support well, and without it, all we can do is try to make mostly theoretical arguments.

Comment: The problem though is that with paleoclimatology, you have a bunch of multi-factor measurements which may mean all kinds of things.  For example tree rings might grow better because it is warmer, there is more water, or a bunch of other factors.  Additionally even there our data is remarkably sparse compared to what we have in the last 60 years.

Comment: This is evidenced by the fact that up until the global warming debate, there was a perpetual debate over whether the medieval warming period was global or more localized to Europe.  That debate has largely moved to one between medieval historians and climatologists over the extent of ice in the North Atlantic, particularly regarding off the North of Scandinavia, Greenland, and Iceland.

Comment: @ChrisTravers, **science** is about multi-factor measurements.  Climate scientists deal with this every day, and use techniques to handle it.  For example, one field that I have to use in my work is that of *data fusion*.  Taking multiple sensor inputs, which each *individually* may represent poor, or noisy data, and combine them together using statistics to get a result that's much **more** precise than the inputs.  That's a result that's completely counterintuitive to someone without a fairly advanced math background.  Then, again, there's the point of us having *multiple* lines of data ...

Comment: ... from independent sources.  When you can look at ice core data **and** tree data from multiple sites **and** sea fossil data, and they tell you the same thing, then you can say that "yes, there was warming, and not simply increased rainfall".  Anyway, I don't think this is helping anyone but you or I at this point.  I'd suggest you checkout a site like http://www.skepticalscience.com/, as it has good layman's descriptions of why common skeptical issues like these are no longer given heavy consideration in the climate science community.

Comment: I have a couple really busy weeks work-wise so my time to respond is relatively short.  Note I am coming at this as someone who has done a lot of early history studies.  One of the things you find there is that we have *very* detailed knowledge of the climate some parts of the globe going back a long ways and this knowledge comes from a wide number of sources, many of which are only available within the domains of archaeology.  We are talking about things like pollen residue in archaeological finds and the like....

Comment: .... So within Europe, Iceland, and Greenland, for example we have tremendously detailed knowledge from archaeologically interesting periods of time and much less knowledge in other times but the Middle Ages are a time we know a lot about from both textual and archaeological records.  We know for example that malaria was endemic to England from 10th century medical manuscripts, and we know that the North Atlantic (and the regions of the Arctic bordering on the North Atlantic) were relatively free of ice during the Medieval Warming Period....

Comment: ... The problem that happens is that most of the time I have seen climatologists talk about the Middle Ages in Europe, they tend to say things we know from the archaeology and written sources aren't really accurate.  This is because they are looking at a subset of the data historians and archaeologists have collected, and so it's sort of like John Franklin failing to ask the Eskimos for help.  This isn't really surprising.  Models are simplifications so we shouldn't really expect computer models of climate to match the historic record.  But that also calls into question other things.

Comment: Just to note, I have spent quite a bit of time looking into the question of how climate variation lead to the rise and fall of the Norse Greenland colonies.  I haven't found any archaeological sources which have used tree rings for climate variation analysis within that domain.  Tree rings are used for dating purposes, but pollen residue in datable objects is what I have seen used most often.  The big problem of course is you can't do that outside an archaeological dig because you have to be able to date the pollen.

Comment: None of this is to say that the earth isn't warming or that humans aren't causing that (I think such a hypothesis is "more likely than not" but not to the level of "beyond reasonable doubt").  It is however to say one can't just trust climate scientists and their computer models.  If they can't model the past based on areas we know a lot about, why should we unconditionally trust their methods generally?  No, I think the strongest evidence for AGW is just the short period of time we've had satellite's in orbit monitoring weather, but evidence < proof.

Comment: Tree rings are also used as a proxy for temperature data, because tree growth increases with temperature, or at least it did until recently (increase in temperature is often driven by an increase in solar radiation, but now is clearly not).  Seach on [dentroclimatalogy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dendroclimatology).  Nobody serious is claiming we should blindly accept the scientific consensus.  The most recent IPCC report, considered the general documentation of that consensus, puts confidence levels at about 90%.  Scientists should largely disregard historians ... history is not science ...

Comment: *Historians* subject us to all manners of religious and political nonsense.  To draw equivalence between the work of historians with that of scientists is flat-out absurd.

Comment: I'd also suggest that if you think you've found instances where *"what we know"* (based on historians' accounts) contradicts climate science results, you post a specific question about that, on the Skeptics, or Geosciences Stack Exchange sites, where they can be adequately addressed.